# Wordpress preg_match apostrophe

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I'm trying to allow only specific symbols in title, which is submitted via ajax call, so I'm using a preg_match, however it turns out apostrophe is going through encoded - `&#039;`, so my preg_match doesn't see it.

```
if (strlen($_POST["meta"]) < 101 && preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9'\-\+:,!&. ]+$/", $_POST["meta"])) {  
//update post title code
}
```

What is the correct work-around to it?

Comment: `if ( preg_match("/\A(?:[a-z0-9'+:,!&. -]|&#039;){1,100}\z/i", $_POST["meta"]) ) {`: But why do you want to do that?

Comment: I want to only allow english characters and symbols only. By default wordpress allows cyrillic and arabic symbols in titles.By the way I solved it the other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I made it this way with [html_entity_decode](https://www.php.net/html_entity_decode)

```
$title = $_POST["meta"];
$title = html_entity_decode($title);

if (strlen($title) < 101 && preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9'\-\+:,!&. ]+$/", $title)) {  
//update post title code
}
```

Comment: Why not, but it also matches `$title="whatever\n";`.